# Can the load in an SGE node be more than the number of CPUs?

Tags: cpu-usage, administration, slots, qsub, sungridengine

I am running a job on a Sun Grid Engine (now known as Oracle Grid Engine) cluster. To see whether my job is slowing down because the node is overloaded, I tried to check the status of the node:

```
$ qstat -l hostname=hnode03 -f
queuename                      qtype resv/used/tot. load_avg arch          states
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
all.q@hnode03.rnd.mycorp.com BP    0/0/0          103.41   lx24-amd64
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
highmem.q@hnode03.rnd.mycorp BP    0/37/40        103.41   lx24-amd64
 977530 0.76963 runJob1 userme       r     09/13/2013 17:53:26     2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
threaded.q@hnode03.rnd.mycor BP    0/24/32        103.41   lx24-amd64
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
workflow.q@hnode03.rnd.mycor B     0/0/0          103.41   lx24-amd64
```

and

```
$ qhost -h hnode03
HOSTNAME                ARCH         NCPU  LOAD  MEMTOT  MEMUSE  SWAPTO  SWAPUS
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
global                  -               -     -       -       -       -       -
hnode03                 lx24-amd64     64 103.4  504.8G  122.9G   16.0G   58.0M
```

Now, the `load_avg` is 103.41, while the `NCPU` is only 64. Is this ever supposed to happen? Are some jobs using CPU than the slots they are assigned?

Update: In response to queries, the configurations are uploaded to http://pastebin.com/hLnJBetS.

Comment: Can you show us the `qconf -se hnode03` output?  Also, `qconf -sq highmem.q` and `qconf -sq threaded.q` would be useful, as well as `qconf -sp {pe}` for any parallel environments that might be configured on the threaded.q.

Comment: @jlp, I've uploaded the configurations to http://pastebin.com/hLnJBetS

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can.

Slots are not synonymous of cores (NCPU). Slots must be seen as "how many jobs can be scheduled in parallel on a node."

If you only want one job to be ran at once, set the slots count for your machines to one.

For the load factor, even if your job only uses one slot, if you have too many threads or subprocesses, then all the cores will be used and the load factor will definitely go above 1.

Comment: Thanks! According to qhost, NCPU is 64, while qstat says number of slots are 40+32=72. The load is higher than both of these numbers. Could it be that the NCPU is wrongly configured or it is counting something like a 2-core as one CPU? Is there a way to know the number of cores from the command line?

Comment: If you're on linux, open "/proc/cpuinfo" and look at the highest "processor" index. (Index, so it starts at 0. If it's 3 then you have 4 cores.)

Comment: What @Finch_Powers said, but keep in mind that a multi-core processor is different from a hyperthreaded processor.  You might look in your machine and see only four processors, but if each is a hexacore proc, you've really got 24 procs.  Don't forget to "accept" his answer as correct so he gets some credit.